# Google Sheets I am writing a macro and trying to skip down several lines of code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, goto

I am rather new to Google Scripts and JavaScript.  I am writing a macro in Google Sheets and I am trying to skip down several lines of code.  The code I am skipping is under development and putting in all those `//` would be a pain and confusing later. This seems like a simple thing to do and have done it many times using Microsoft VBA.  The only thing I can find in Google Scripts uses a label and a goto statement but that only seems to apply when the goto jumps to an earlier place in the macro.

I am just trying to jump down a couple of lines of code without using `//`.

Any help will be Greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `Goto` you are doing it wrong. Also in VBA you should never need to use `Goto` anywhere else than in error handling code. Instead of `Goto` use `If … Else … End If` structures. This way code would only run if a condition is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a block comment to skip multiple lines permanently:

```
function myFunction() {
  /* 
  Browser.msgBox('This is skipped.');
  Browser.msgBox('This is skipped too.');
  */

  Browser.msgBox('This runs.');
}
```

Alternatively use an `If` statement and set a switch for debug mode. So you can switch your code execution from production mode into debug mode to run a different code.

```
var debugmode = true;
if (debugmode) {
  Browser.msgBox('This runs only in debug mode.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peh.  The /* ... */ was just what I was looking for. :-)